# A simple basic Python3 question which I don't Understand

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist

**Question:**

Fill in the function body for the Python3 function longestWord (you should leave the function header as it appears).

The function takes a single input argument which we assume is a list of strings, with each string forming one English word.  The output should be a word from the list which has the greatest number of letters.

You must use a for loop to write this function.

**Answer:**

```
def longestWord(listOfWords):
    biggestWord = listOfWords[0]
    biggestNum = len(biggestWord)
    for word in listOfWords:
        num = len(word)
        if num>biggestNum:
            biggestNum=num
            biggestWord=word
    return biggestWord

print(longestWord(["Hello", "Goodbye"]))
```

I understand the first three lines. It takes the first value in the list and saves the length of the word inputted. However i don't understand the rest of the code. How does it compare the two inputted words to output the longest one. What is num and word?. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a Python question. Why is it tagged "C++" and why does it say C++ rather than Python in the title? There is *no* C++ here.

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please always use a question headline that describes your question or problem in few words instead of saying "I have a question..." so that the experts here can easier find questions they can answer by just reading the headlines. THX :-)

Comment: I typed c++ by mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to inform you that this question is about Python3 and not C++. Anyways, what the code is doing is it's taking the first word and stores it in a variable called `biggestWord`. and storing the length of `biggestWord` in a variable called `biggestNum`. Then for each word in `listOfWords`, it stores the word in a variable called `word` and stroing the length of it in variable called `num`. Then it compares `num` and `biggestNum`. If the length of some word i.e. `num` is bigger than the biggest length up until now, i.e. `biggestNum`, then it puts `num` in `biggestNum` to indicate that that's the biggest number up until now. and puts `word` in `biggestWord` replacing the old word. Then it returns the word with the biggest length, i.e. `biggestWord`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where C++ came from, i meant Python3. This line was confusing me 'for word in listOfWords:' I thought 'word' was a function. I took a lesson on for loops and now I understand. Thank you.